# Add UserControl on WinForm pythonnet

Tags: python, .net, winforms, python.net, pythonnet

I am trying to add UserControl to a WinForm using PythonNet but not having any luck. For testing, I added a button and that shows up but not the UserControl and I am not sure what I a doing wrong.

All the code can be placed into one py file. I broke into a few sections hoping it will be easier to read.

USER CONTROL

```
class Field(WinForms.UserControl):

    def __init__(self):
        self.InitializeComponents()
        pass

    def InitializeComponents(self):
        self.components = System.ComponentModel.Container()

        self.label = WinForms.Label()
        self.textBox = WinForms.Label()


        ## Label
        # self.label.Anchor = ((WinForms.AnchorStyles)(
        #     ((WinForms.AnchorStyles.Top | WinForms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
        #      | WinForms.AnchorStyles.Left)))
        self.label.AutoSize = True
        self.label.Location = System.Drawing.Point(3, 7)
        self.label.Name = "label"
        self.label.Size = System.Drawing.Size(29, 13)
        self.label.TabIndex = 0
        self.label.Text = "label"


        ## TextBox
        # self.textBox.Anchor = ((WinForms.AnchorStyles)(
        #     (((WinForms.AnchorStyles.Top | WinForms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
        #       | WinForms.AnchorStyles.Left)
        #      | WinForms.AnchorStyles.Right)))
        # self.textBox.Location = System.Drawing.Point(115, 3)
        self.textBox.Name = "textBox"
        self.textBox.Size = System.Drawing.Size(260, 20)
        self.textBox.TabIndex = 1


        ## Control
        self.AutoScaleMode = WinForms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        self.Controls.Add(self.textBox)
        self.Controls.Add(self.label)
        self.Name = "Field"
        self.Size = System.Drawing.Size(378, 26)
        # self.PerformLayout()
```

PARENT FORM

```
class ParentForm(WinForms.Form):

    def __init__(self):
        self.InitializeComponents()

    # region Form Design

    def InitializeComponents(self):
        self.components = System.ComponentModel.Container()
        self.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        self.ClientSize = System.Drawing.Size(385, 180)
        self.Name = "ParentForm"
        self.Text = "Parent Form"


        self.field1 = Field()
        self.field1.Location = Point(13, 13)
        self.field1.Name = "field1"
        self.field1.Size = Size(378, 26)
        self.field1.TabIndex = 1
        self.Controls.Add(self.field1)


        self.button1 = WinForms.Button()
        self.button1.Location = Point(13, 50)
        self.button1.Size = Size(50, 20)
        self.button1.Text = "Button1"
        self.Controls.Add(self.button1)
        pass


    def Dispose(self):
        self.components.Dispose()
        WinForms.Form.Dispose(self)
```

ENTRY POINT AND IMPORTS

```
import clr
import System
import System.Windows.Forms as WinForms

from System.IO import File
from System.Text import Encoding
from System.Drawing import Color, Point, Size
from System.Threading import ApartmentState, Thread, ThreadStart



def appThread():
    app = ParentForm()
    WinForms.Application.Run(app)
    app.Dispose()


def appEntry():
    thread = Thread(ThreadStart(appThread))
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
    thread.Start()
    thread.Join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    appEntry()
```

Comment: you may need to define `__namespace__`: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/master/src/tests/test_subclass.py